# Dash - How to clear figure and dropdowns with a reset button

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have one figure which needs 2 inputs from 2 dropdowns.
I want to have a reset button that clears the 3 of them.

So far I've managed to reset the dropdowns with the button but I can't figure out how to clear everything.
If I try to add the Figure in the `reset` output, my app isn't working anymore.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Output, Input, callback
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            options=df['continent'].unique(),
            placeholder="Select a continent",
            clearable=True,
            id='continent'
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            value=None,
            placeholder="Select a country",
            clearable=True,
            id='country',
            disabled=True
        )
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
),

    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
        
    html.Button(id='reset',children = 'Reset'),
    
    html.Div(id='text')
])


@callback(
    Output(component_id='country', component_property='options'),
    Output(component_id='country', component_property='disabled'),
    Input(component_id='continent', component_property='value')
)
def update_text(continent_val):
    return (df.country[df.continent == continent_val].unique(),
            False)
    
@callback(
    Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='continent', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='country', component_property='value')
    )
def update_fig(continent_val, country_val):
    if (continent_val is None) or (country_val is None):
        raise PreventUpdate()
    else:
        mask = (df.continent == continent_val) & (df.country == country_val)
        dff = df[mask]
        fig = px.line(dff, x='year', y='lifeExp')
        fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
        return fig
        
    
@callback(
    Output(component_id='continent',component_property='value'),
    Output(component_id='country',component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='reset',component_property='n_clicks')
    )
def reset(nclick):
    if nclick != 0:
        return (None,None)
    
@callback(
    Output('text','children'),
    Input('reset','n_clicks')
    )
def text(nclick):
    return 'Button has been clicked {} times'.format(nclick)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8004)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes:**

- You can merge the second and the third callback together.
- You can use `callback_context` to detect when you click on reset.
- I use the last version of Dash 2.6.2, if `ctx` does not work with you, try to use `callback_context` instead of `ctx`or try to upgrade your Dash.

**Code:**

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Output, Input, callback,ctx
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            options=df['continent'].unique(),
            placeholder="Select a continent",
            clearable=True,
            id='continent'
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            value=None,
            placeholder="Select a country",
            clearable=True,
            id='country',
            disabled=True
        )
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
),

    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
        
    html.Button(id='reset',children = 'Reset'),
    
    html.Div(id='text')
])


@callback(
    Output(component_id='country', component_property='options'),
    Output(component_id='country', component_property='disabled'),
    Input(component_id='continent', component_property='value')
)
def update_text(continent_val):
    return (df.country[df.continent == continent_val].unique(),
            False)
    
@callback(
    Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
    Output(component_id='continent', component_property='value'),
    Output(component_id='country', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='continent', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='country', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='reset', component_property='n_clicks')
    )
def update_fig(continent_val, country_val,n_clicks):

    if ctx.triggered_id == "reset":
        return ({},None,None)
    
    elif (continent_val is not None) and (country_val is not None):
            mask = (df.continent == continent_val) & (df.country == country_val)
            dff = df[mask]
            fig = px.line(dff, x='year', y='lifeExp')
            fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
            return fig,continent_val,country_val
    
    return dash.no_update
 
    
@callback(
    Output('text','children'),
    Input('reset','n_clicks')
    )
def text(nclick):
    return 'Button has been clicked {} times'.format(nclick)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8004)
```

**Output:**

[image]